# Failed to enable constraints - Do I need to Compile? .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net

Very new to .Net. Everything was working fine until I added `<Tracking>` to my XML file:

```
<Product>
    <id>product1</id>
    <Name>Product 1</Name>
    <Packart>detailimg</Packart>
    <TitleFile>detailtitleoriginal</TitleFile>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <Ingredients>Ingredients</Ingredients>
    <FeedingInstructions>Instructions</FeedingInstructions>
    <Analysis>Analysis</Analysis>
    <Footer>Footer</Footer>
    **<Tracking>Test</Tracking>**
</Product>
```

My XSD file is such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Products">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Product">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Packart" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="TitleFile" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Ingredients" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="FeedingInstructions" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Analysis" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Footer" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Tracking" type="xs:string" /></xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then in my aspx page I added:

`<%=row[ "Tracking"]%>`

When I view the page in a browser I get the error:

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Source Error: 


Line 19:             ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
Line 20:             ds.ReadXmlSchema(MapPath("Content/xml/Products.xsd"));
Line 21:             ds.ReadXml(MapPath("Content/xml/Products.xml"));
Line 22:             Cache.Insert("Products", ds, new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(MapPath("Content/xml/Products.xml")),
Line 23:                          DateTime.Now.AddHours(12), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

Source File: d:\ProductDetails.aspx.cs    Line: 21
```

Comment: Can you give more details? What data tables do you have? Is it only Products? Or are there more tables?

Comment: And... you didn't actually add stars (* * <Tracking>Test</Tracking> * *) to your XML, did you?

Comment: Sorry, the ** are Stackoverflow formatting for bold gone awry. As for data tables, I am sure there are more. But I inherited this site and I'm rather unfamiliar with .Net. If it helps, here is the top of the asp page: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProductDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProductDetails" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" ValidateRequest="false" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" TagName="footer" TagPrefix="uc" %>`

Comment: Can you show us what is the type of "ds" variable? I see that on line 19 you initialize it to System.Data.DataSet, but maybe it is defined as typed dataset before?

Comment: `System.Data.DataSet ds = (System.Data.DataSet)Cache["Products"];
         if (ds == null)
         {
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            ds.ReadXmlSchema(MapPath("Content/xml/Products.xsd"));
            ds.ReadXml(MapPath("Content/xml/Products.xml"));
            Cache.Insert("Products", ds, new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(MapPath("Content/xml/Products.xml")),
                         DateTime.Now.AddHours(12), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
         }`

Comment: I guess Cache["Products"] contains a typed dataset which has constraints. Ypu should check what is the type of that data set, and check tables and constrains.

Comment: Thanks. And just to be clear: I'd need to do that in Visual Studio, right?

Comment: Yes, but I guess you need some knowledge on typed datasets, you can read an article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss7fbaez(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to overcome this issue quickly is to disable EnforceConstraints on the dataset:

```
ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
//now you can load the data
```

**UPDATE**: This may have unwanted repercussions, obviously. You should decide whether this is the case or not in your scenario.

Comment: Comment for downvote: you should not disable constraints if they are required. Provided solution may bring in more problems and does not guarantee that your problem will be solved, since the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: Could this have any unwanted repercussions?

Comment: @Dima: Fair enough, I added a "disclaimer" to my answer. The problem at hand will be solved for sure and this may very well be safe to do. But again, it needs to be analyzed from the context on which this code will be used.